# Unable to capture inputs from EventHub into Stream Analytics

Tags: azure-eventhub, cortana-intelligence, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I am able to send messages from my application to eventhub.
However I  am unable to input those messages in Stream Analytics.

Comment: Can you describe the issue in more detail? Did you start the ASA job, do you see any errors in operation logs?

Comment: @vignesh-chandramohan Hi Vignesh, I am using the azure service for the first time. I am able to send json messages to event hub but unable to fetch them in the streams input. Links below are the screenshots of eventhub n Stream. http://i65.tinypic.com/2z8p0xx.png     http://i68.tinypic.com/jt3rpv.png    http://i64.tinypic.com/2enq1ll.png

Comment: Can you check Operation logs for this ASA job? Does it give you any errors?

Comment: @vignesh-chandramohan I cant see any error or warning in the logs. http://i66.tinypic.com/3038cwz.png                                      DO I need to explicitly define a error rule or log??

Comment: @PrateekMane did you get this working? Is there any issue coming up in the Operation Logs in the Azure portal?

Comment: Hi Saurabh, I am still facing the issue. I cant see any wrnings or errors in the log file.

Answer (score 1):

you should use [Operations Logs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-operation-logs/) for defining what is going on with your stream. If there are problems with incoming messages, there can be the situation that you will not see any problems in the Dashboard.

One of the most popular issues is the format of the data, so check if your SQL query use the same schema as the incoming message and the same format.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I deleted the input and re-created it just like the first time (except I gave it a new name). I am sure I had done this before without success. But this time it is working.